# Activity indicator is not in centered in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiactivityindicatorview

I want show `activity indicator` in `TableView` with `NIB/XIB` file, but it shown is not in center, it placed in right side

I do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    actInd.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    actInd.center = self.view.center
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    self.view.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Remove your code from ViewDidLoad and Place your code in ViewDidAppear

Comment: ...Or at least, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Since autolayout was introduced (I think), subview frames are not consolidated yet by the time `viewDidLoad()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    actInd.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    self.view.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    actInd.center = self.view.center
}

/* Following two functions are acceptable also.
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    actInd.center = self.view.center
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { 
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    actInd.center = self.view.center
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach works for me.

```
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow { 
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.width/2, y: window.frame.height/2, width: 0, height: 0)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white

        window.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- add the `UIActivityIndicator` in your XIB/Storyboard
- set it to `hidden` (in Storyboard)
- create an `IBOutlet`
- toggle `spinner.isHidden` when ever you want to show/hide it.

Comment: This is what **I** would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using table-cells you need to use **autoresizingMask** ,so receiver resizes itself when its superview’s bounds change.
Below approach worked for me.

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
activityIndicator.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64)
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        
//        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width  / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))
        
activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: UIView.AutoresizingMask.RawValue(UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleRightMargin.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleLeftMargin.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleBottomMargin.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleTopMargin.rawValue))))
    
self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```